# Compile c++ code with IDE, error at the second time

Tags: c++, windows-8, ide, g++, mingw

I'm a fresh c++ user in Windows 8 system. I have installed MinGW and setup the environment variables. I create the simplest hellow world code as below

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        cout<<"hello world"<<endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

It works well at the first time, but when I do some small modification, for example delete "hello", and then build and run the project again. I found that the program will keep running without end. The command line keeps showing:

```
    Current working directory: C:\Users\cr\Documents\project\helloworld\Debug
    Running program: le_exec.exe ./helloworld
```

If I try to build it again, it shows

```
    make.exe[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld'
    C:/Users/cr/MinGW/bin/g++.exe  -c  "C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld/main.cpp" -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.cpp.o -I. -I.
    C:/Users/cr/MinGW/bin/g++.exe -o ./Debug/helloworld @"helloworld.txt" -L.
    c:/users/cr/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file ./Debug/helloworld.exe: Permission denied
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
    make.exe[1]: *** [Debug/helloworld] Error 1
    helloworld.mk:78: recipe for target 'Debug/helloworld' failed
    make.exe[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld'
    make.exe: *** [All] Error 2
    Makefile:4: recipe for target 'All' failed
    ====1 errors, 0 warnings====
```

I could not even delete the executable file "helloworld.exe" because it is using in 'System' until I restart the computer.

Update:
I can compile it in the command line:

```
    C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld>g++ main.cpp -o test.exe

    C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld>test.exe
```

It will then keep running until I close the command line window. If I open a new command line window and compile the file again. There is no problem.

Update2:
Problem also happens when I compile the cpp file the second time even if the file has not been edited.

```
C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld>g++ main.cpp -o test.exe

C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld>test.exe
hello world

C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld>g++ main.cpp -o test2.exe

C:/Users/cr/Documents/project/helloworld>test2.exe
```

It keeps running here.

Comment: *but when I do some small modification* -- Please show us this "small modification".  Don't just describe it.

Comment: For example, I edit this line: cout<<"hello world"<<endl; change it to cout<<"world"<<endl;

Comment: Odd and peculiar. Does a walk through with a debugger give any hints as to where it is hung up?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I struggled with it for a whole day. The problem is anti-virus software...... I set it inactive and all things do well...
I don't want to point out what this software is, but just want to give out a reminder for this problem....